# 403 - Forbidden Error on Dashboard Modules

Tags: drupal, civireport, dashboard, pdf

We suddenly started receiving a "403 - Forbidden Error" on the dashboard modules. This is not an issue itself, however, at the same time the gridlines on the PDF reports have disappeared. Are these two issues connected? Either way any reason as to why the gridlines have disappeared?

We are running CiviCRM 4.6.10 on drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both could be related when the URL settings are wrong. 
Admin - Settings - Resource URLs and
Admin - Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths

I have seen it gone wrong by things as simple as: enforcing www or https.

Comment: The "www" vs "no www" or "https" vs "http" is almost certainly correct here.  Ben, please open your web browser's developer tools ("F12" button) and go to the "Net" tab and reload the page.  Find the dashlets (should be easy to find, since they have an error), and compare the requested URL with the one in your address bar for HTTP vs. HTTPS and www vs. no www.